# How to Calulate the difference between 10 or more unix timestamps in python in a list in minutes and average them

Tags: python

So am trying to make a loop that takes a list of of unix time stamps and fines the difference of all the timestamps in the list i know am being stupid :P idk

I can't figure it out as the system for loops gives you less to work with in python or i could be wrong am trying to use a for loop.

Am trying to find the average difference of time between each event that goes on. Any help would be great i was looking through the python stack exchange ones and all  the answers was for two time stamps when i need multiple. Thank you :P and it may come in random orders also so am probably stupid and this is easy or something

```
1535172255 - 1535170219 value
1535172255 - 1535170219 value2
1535172255 - 1535170219 value3
```

etc etc

```
Then i would average them 
fullvalue = value + value2 + value3 
finalvalue = finalvalue / 3
```

Comment: update your sample list, input and attempt; in your question all three timestamps you are taking difference are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort the timestamps in order, push their difference in a list and then compute the mean using something like this (pass the list to the mean function):

```
#python 3

def mean(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)

a = [4,2,8,10,6] # Timestamps
diff = [] #Difference of timestamps
a.sort()
print(a)
prev = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i], prev)
    if (i > 0):
        diff.append (a[i] - prev)
    prev = a[i]
print("Difference of timestamp list is", diff)
print(mean(diff))
```

Comment: Sweet i just had to add a divide by 60 to the return to get it in minutes and it worked thank you :).